# strange unterminated string literal error with Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have seen similar issues to the below but I've thoroughly checked the following problem.  I receive an "Unterminated string literal" error in Firefox's console.

I have an HTML page as follows:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>

<SCRIPT type="text/JavaScript">
var test = "</script>";
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

As far as I can tell, there should be nothing invalid about this JavaScript since I don't believe '<', '/' or '>' to need escaping when used as part of a JavaScript string variable. In fact the following works:

```
var test = "</>";
```

So, I am wondering how my little script is managing to trip up the browser or how I can work around it?

Answer (score 5):

Its not the js you have to worry about its the html.
The html parser reads your `"</script>"` string as an end tag closing the script tag, ending the script. So the js interpreter sees

```
var test = "
```

To avoid this you can use an escape trick

```
<SCRIPT type="text/JavaScript">
var test = "<\/script>";
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: I had to run this myself to check it. I had no idea this would happen. Nice explaining! +1.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! I guess my server-side JSON library must not be escaping as you suggested, I will go investigate!

Comment: That is interesting. Why does it parse through the quotation mark for the html tag?

Comment: @TravisJ: The HTML parser doesn't know about JavaScript. It only sees characters between tags.